# React Router only render '/' none of other routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

My react router is having unexpected behavior.

routes.js

```
   import React from 'react'
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

    import { Login, Recover, Home } from '../Pages'

    const Routes =(
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
          <Route path="/recover" component={Recover} />
          <Route path="*" render={() => <h1>Page not found</h1>} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    )

    export default Routes
    export { Routes }
```

and my index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import Routes from './Services/routes'

ReactDOM.render(Routes, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Only the components I put in '/' work, what can it be?

When I try open /login or /recover the browser render Cannot GET /login or Cannot GET /recover

Comment: do you get any errors in console?

Comment: no errors in console

Comment: What paths do you type in the address bar?

Comment: /login & /recover, both show Cannot GET /login or Cannot GET /recover

Comment: `const Routes` should be a function, isn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: Function didnt work, this article didint help much. I try isolate route buy still getting cannot get. I think is cause webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing webpack config add

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: outputPath,
    publicPath: '/',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    host: 'localhost'
  },
```

then works